# Oracle: Value from main query is not available in subquery

Tags: oracle, function, window, subquery

I have this query, and one of its column is a subquery that should be bringing a list of values using a listagg function. This list has its starting point as the `S.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA` value. The list is a should be, it always has values.

The listagg function is consuming an inline view that uses a window function to create the list.

```
select *
from (
         SELECT DISTINCT S.ID_SOLICITACAO,
                         S.NR_PROTOCOLO_SOLICITACAO,
                         S.DH_INCLUSAO,
                         S.ID_USUARIO,
                         U.NR_CPF,
                         OI.ID_MODULO,
                         OI.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA,
                         OI.NO_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA,
                         R.ID_ATRIBUICAO,
                         P.ID_PERMISSAO,
                         1 AS            TIPO_NOTIFICACAO,
                         (
                             select LISTAGG(oc6.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA || '-' || oc6.ord || '-', '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY oc6.ord) eai
                             from (
                                      SELECT oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA,
                                             oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA_PAI,
                                             oc1.SG_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA,
                                             rownum as ord
                                      FROM TB_ORGAO_INTERNO oc1
                                      WHERE oc1.DH_EXCLUSAO is null
                                            -- THE VALUE FROM S.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA IS NOT AVAILBLE HERE
                                      START WITH oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA = S.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA
                                      CONNECT BY prior oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA_PAI = oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA
                         ) oc6) aproPrec

         FROM TB_SOLICITACAO S
                  INNER JOIN TB_ORGAO_INTERNO OI ON S.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA = OI.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA
                  INNER JOIN TB_RELACIONAMENTO_ATRIBUICAO R
                             ON (R.ID_MODULO = OI.ID_MODULO AND R.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA IS NULL AND
                                 R.ID_SOLICITACAO IS NULL)
                  INNER JOIN TB_PERMISSAO P
                             ON (P.ID_USUARIO = :usuario AND P.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA = :orgao AND
                                 P.ID_ATRIBUICAO = R.ID_ATRIBUICAO)
                  INNER JOIN TB_USUARIO U ON (U.ID_USUARIO = S.ID_USUARIO)
         WHERE 1 = 1
           AND U.DH_EXCLUSAO IS NULL
           AND P.DH_EXCLUSAO IS NULL
           AND S.DH_EXCLUSAO IS NULL
           AND OI.DH_EXCLUSAO IS NULL
           AND R.ID_ATRIBUICAO IN :atribuicoes
           AND P.ID_STATUS_PERMISSAO = 7
           AND OI.ID_MODULO = 1
           AND S.ID_STATUS_SOLICITACAO IN (1, 2, 5, 6)
           and s.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA in (SELECT DISTINCT o.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA
                                           FROM TB_ORGAO_INTERNO o
                                           WHERE o.DH_EXCLUSAO IS NULL
                                           START WITH o.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA = 3
                                           CONNECT BY PRIOR o.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA = o.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA_PAI)
     );
```

The problem is that the `aproPrec` column is always returning `null` as its result.

If I force the criteria to have the `S.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA` hardcoded, the list returns its true value.

If I chance this:

`START WITH oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA = S.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA`

To this:

`START WITH oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA = 311`

where 311 is the value that the `S.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA` column really has.

Is there a way to make this query works as 'I think' it should work?

Comment: if it was not available (by which I mean 'legal'), you would have gotten an error. Which version are you using? Can you provide a simplified version with reproducible test case?

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, I changed the subquery by this another one:

```
(
    select qt_.*
    from (
             SELECT QRY_NAME.*,
                    rownum as ord
             FROM (
                      SELECT oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA,
                             oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA_PAI,
                             connect_by_root (oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA) as root
                      FROM TB_ORGAO_INTERNO oc1
                      CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA_PAI = oc1.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA
                  ) QRY_NAME
             WHERE root = s.ID_ORGAO_INTELIGENCIA
         ) qt_
)
```